# 2sxc : Query designer - less than or empty (and / or)

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I have entity with field "DateEnd" that is not required.

I want to make query with query designer to filter all items with "DateEnd" field les than value (eg.:"2016-06-01") or empty value for "DateEnd"

I know that I can add value filter with:
Attribute=EndDate, Value=2016-06-01, Operator='<='

to get all items with "DateEnd" entered, but then items with not entered date are missing.

Is posible to make query in designer to return me also this items with date null values?

---

Edited:

If I "chain" value filters I can get "AND" operation for filters, but how "OR" operator can be done?

Comment: also how "between" operator work? where to put values? http://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/9259

Comment: for the between you have to enter somethnig like `2015-03-02 and 2016-03-01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now - 2sxc 8.5 - there is no "also include nulls" feature. I believe the best way to do it quickly would be to

1. create one stream with your condition, returning only those <= ...
2. create another stream with the null-condition, returning only those = nothing
3. Merge these streams in your template

note that I'm not sure if the null-condition actually works, maybe we should add this as a special value or operator or something - would appreciate your feedback

if many people think a merge-stream datasource would be of value, post it as a request to the issues.

Comment: I think that now all can be done inside query designer: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/using-stream-merge-and-item-filter-duplicates-in-2sxc-9-10